# Eslint still changing double quotes to single quotes

Tags: react-native, eslint

This is my first time with eslint so if I have missed any info below please do let me know with the comments. I have a react native project and have configured eslint in it. Here are my rules:

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es6": true,
        "node": true,
            "react-native/react-native": true,

    },
    "extends": "eslint:recommended",
    "globals": {
        "Atomics": "readonly",
        "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": 2018,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react",
            "react-native"
    ],
    "rules": {
      "quotes": [2, "double", "avoid-escape"],
            "semi": [
          "error",
            "always"
      ],
            "indent": [
            "error",
            2
        ],
            "linebreak-style": [
                    "error",
                    "unix"
            ],
            "react-native/no-unused-styles": 2,
            "react-native/split-platform-components": 2,
            "react-native/no-inline-styles": 2,
            "react-native/no-color-literals": 2,
            "react-native/no-raw-text": 2,
            "object-curly-spacing": [2, "always", {
                "objectsInObjects": true,
                "arraysInObjects": true
            }]
    }
}
```

As you can see two important rules here about quotes and object-curly-spacing. Even though I have set quotes to double but still when I do yarn lint --fix it gives me warning that

> warning  Strings must use singlequote

and with the --fix flag it changes to single quotes. What I am doing wrong here please explain.

Similarly with object-curly-spacing set to "always" my imports are changed from having spaces in objects to no space i.e from { test } to {test}.

I want strings in double quotes and spaces after and before object literals.

Comment: "*warning Strings must use singlequote*" where is this coming from? ESLint or elsewhere? Some editors might come with their own configuration that conflicts with the project config (I've seen Visual Studio do that). If it's actually ESLint - make sure it's picking up the correct configuration for the project.

Comment: @VLAZ I am using VS Code and this comes when I run the eslint . command or yarn lint command

Comment: by any chance, are you using `prettier`?

Comment: @kenmistry sir I was using prettier but I have removed it. I am getting prettier/prettier in some errors during eslint though.

Comment: You mind editing to show your directory structure. It is clesr eslint is not rsadjng your `.eslintrc.json`